# Split/join a binary file into multiple parts without loading file into memory?

Tags: java

In Java, how do you split a binary file into multiple parts while only loading a small portion of the File into memory at one time?

So I have a file **FullFile** that is large. I need to upload it to cloud storage but it's so large that it often times out.

I can make this problem less likely if I split the file and upload in chunks.

So I need to split **FullFile** into files of chunk size `MaxChunkSize`.

- `List<File> fileSplit(File fullFile, int maxChunkSize)`
- `File fileJoin(List<File> splitFiles)`

Most code snippets around require the file to be text. But in my case the files are compressed binary.

What would be the best way to implement these methods?

Comment: You would simply want to use [`Files#newInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newInputStream(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) and use the [`InputStream#read`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)) method to read a small portion of the file at a time. Then make a `Files#newOutputStream` for each file that you want to output and write to it from your InputStream.

Comment: i updated for clarity whoever -1'd me. sorry for the lack of detail.

Comment: @Rubydesic yeah agreed. I just get the feeling someone already has this sitting in one of their workspaces and can copy paste some battle tested solution. Me typing something out is likely to be buggy (Until unit tested) when someone may already have it hashed out.

Comment: If they're *large*-large I'd probably use NIO channels (and there may be something even better now). There would be very little to unit-test.

Comment: You can look into DataInputStream. Its lets you read bytes. Wrap the FileInputStream with a DataInputStream. After that you can read the amount of bytes required into a ByteArrayOutputStream (these can be your file chunks). Then operate on the chunks as you build them, this way only one chunk at a time will be read into memory.
I will try to post a full answer later, if need be. Let me know if it works

Comment: OK I have crafted up something I will post it in a couple days. Otherwise might discourage others from answering

Comment: How are you going to reverse the split (a Unix `join`) after upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the full answer:

- The **maxChunkSize** represents the **size in bytes** of a **file chunk**.
- In the example below I read a **5mb zip** file and split it into five **1MB** chunks and later join them back using the fileJoin function.
- The method **stageLocally** stages the files locally but you can modify it to work with any cloud storage. (*Better to abstract this out so you can switch between multiple storage implementations*)
- You can tweak **maxChunkSize** based on the amount of data you want to store **inmemory** at a given time
- The `IOutils.copy()` methods is from the commons library, [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io) is the maven link. You can also use `Files.copy()` in liue of it. The `Files.copy()` methods comes from the `java.nio` package, so you don't have to add an external dependency to use it.

I have ommitted the exception handling for brevity.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File input = new File(_5_MB_FILE_PATH);
    File outPut = fileJoin(split(input, 1_024_000));

    System.out.println(IOUtils.contentEquals(Files.newInputStream(input.toPath()), Files.newInputStream(outPut.toPath())));

}

public static List<File> split(File largeFile, int maxChunkSize) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(largeFile.toPath());
    List<File> list = new ArrayList<>();
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[maxChunkSize];
    int dataRead = in.read(buffer);
    while (dataRead > -1) {
        list.add(stageLocally(buffer, dataRead));
        dataRead = in.read(buffer);
    }
    return list;
}

private static File stageLocally(byte[] buffer, int length) throws IOException {
    File outPutFile = File.createTempFile("temp-", "split", new File(TEMP_DIRECTORY));
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outPutFile);
    fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
    fos.close();
    return outPutFile;
}


public static File fileJoin(List<File> list) throws IOException {
    File outPutFile = File.createTempFile("temp-", "unsplit", new File(TEMP_DIRECTORY));
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outPutFile);
    for (File file : list) {
        InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(file.toPath());
        IOUtils.copy(in, fileOutputStream);
        in.close();
    }
    fileOutputStream.close();
    return outPutFile;
}
```

Let me know if this helps.